# canceling timers during weblogic shutdown

Tags: timer, weblogic, shutdown

i have an EAR project which runs on weblogic

i have some timers in my application

and i want to cancel them when i redeploy my EAR project.

I have tried using PhaseListener but i could not access to my web module classes in phase listener.

how could i do this task?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I did this by creating a servlet that implements ServletContextListener.  I start the timer in the contextInitialized method, and stop it in the contextDestroyed method.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually cancel the jobs server by server.
In Weblogic console -> select server -> control -> jobs

select the job(s) to cancel.